# How to use promise.allSettled with typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

Typescript build is failing as it does not seem to like `Promise.allSetttled` even though I have set ts config comilerOptions with `"lib": [ "ES2020.Promise" ],`

It seems as though the response for `promise.allSettled` does not include `result` or `reason`.

When running typescript build I get the following error:

```
Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<IMyPromiseResult>'.
```

and

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult'.
```

My code block looks like this and as you can see, I am trying to access `reason` and `result` from eaech of the promises that get resolved.

```
const myPromise = async () : Promise<IMyPromiseResult> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("hello world")
  })
}

const data = await Promise.allSettled([
  myPromise()
]);

const response = data.find(res => res.status === 'fulfilled')?.result;

if(!response) {
  const error = data.find(res => res.status === 'rejected')?.reason;
  throw new Error(error);
}
```

How can I update the Promise.allSettled declaration to include the correct interfaces?

Comment: From your result handling code it looks like what you're actually looking for is [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)?

Comment: The problem would be that a `PromiseSettledResult` is a discriminated union, and although you are using `find` with the appropriate predicate, Typescript is not clever enough to cast the `find` result to the respective `PromiseFulfilledResult`/`PromiseRejectedResult`.

Comment: @Bergi yes you are right that `Promise.any` would be better but unfortunately it is not available in the version of node I am using

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like Bergi mentioned TypeScript does not know if the type is `PromiseFulfilledResult` / `PromiseRejectedResult` when checking types.

The only way is to cast the promise result. This can be done because you already verified that the resolved promise is either fulfilled or rejected.

See this example:

```js
const myPromise = async (): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("hello world");
  });
};

const data = await Promise.allSettled([myPromise()]);

const response = (data.find(
  (res) => res.status === "fulfilled"
) as PromiseFulfilledResult<string> | undefined)?.value;

if (!response) {
  const error = (data.find(
    (res) => res.status === "rejected"
  ) as PromiseRejectedResult | undefined)?.reason;
  throw new Error(error);
}
```

Comment: Should be `| undefined` though as `find` might not return a result.

Comment: Casting is **not** the only way, please do not cast but check other answers instead.

Answer (score 44):

Like [bela53](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64930124/3349511) stated, use type guards. A more elegant solution than to inline the type guards is to define them as separate functions, and with generics binding you'd get the correct value too for the fulfilled promises, and can reuse for any `allSettled` filtering needs.

Casting is not needed (and generally should be avoided).

```js
const isRejected = (input: PromiseSettledResult<unknown>): input is PromiseRejectedResult => 
  input.status === 'rejected'

const isFulfilled = <T>(input: PromiseSettledResult<T>): input is PromiseFulfilledResult<T> => 
  input.status === 'fulfilled'

const myPromise = async () => Promise.resolve("hello world");

const data = await Promise.allSettled([myPromise()]);

const response = data.find(isFulfilled)?.value
const error = data.find(isRejected)?.reason
```

Comment: Try this solution but lint complain with this [rule](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/v40.1.0/docs/rules/no-array-callback-reference.md) , and it really has a point. It's a matter of taste, but I would go with bela53 answer. Comment this because I took a time to get to that answer, and maybe it help other kkkkkk

Comment: @DaniloMourelle you could of course for avoiding that do `.find((res) => isFulfilled(res))` so you wouldn't need to add typeguard definition to every single place where you would need to do this check.

Comment: wow. I could have wrote this but would have taken me hours. My lucky google search was "typescript promise.allSettled utility type filter rejected fulfilled" but a more wordy version could be be "typescript utility type to filter promise.allSettled result for fulfilled promises (with type predicates and generics)"

Answer (score 25):

Use a type guard:

```
const isFulfilled = <T,>(p:PromiseSettledResult<T>): p is PromiseFulfilledResult<T> => p.status === 'fulfilled';
const isRejected = <T,>(p:PromiseSettledResult<T>): p is PromiseRejectedResult => p.status === 'rejected';

const results = await Promise.allSettled(...);
const fulfilledValues = results.filter(isFulfilled).map(p => p.value);
const rejectedReasons = results.filter(isRejected).map(p => p.reason);
```

Answer (score 4):

Define the `find` callback as type guard, that returns a type predicate:

```
type IMyPromiseResult = string

const response = data.find(
  (res): res is PromiseFulfilledResult<string> => res.status === 'fulfilled'
)?.value;

if (!response) {
  const error = data.find(
    (res): res is PromiseRejectedResult => res.status === 'rejected'
  )?.reason;
  throw new Error(error);
}
```

[Demo Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLbFRACgEoYBvAKBipikxGRzAAUAndbVEAUxgF4ZQkWMQBcMVu05cAPAEkAsszYduAJS4gEAG2QA%20PvorVjMFl2QIWWCFwDu45VIIEzIdFoBuXEr0OUTAa7uXgQARAAWXFpa6DC26CxaACahRP4BAL5pxhnk6TR0DEnAyMB8ArZ4DBIqXAB0wNEAyubIWlxJBADa%20cbYSpLcxPkAukQA3HnGyGAADjwKA7Xqmjrl9Cz4AOZT1LQQ9KYas3Q8-MWldXD4nb3ULhpEYq4wnA6DXABi2tfRHSvaZDSDbbfS%20I4gOr0EoIEB8Xj8ADkiC0v3aSUR%20SIAH46h5GgguJN8qg4DACABCVwnA7eMh3Kj7Q5cFhsFjlC7AK43AgMkwPEBPCGvOE1KTqABWXCgyH%20GkBBghUNKFjhCKRZilMo6mICVBxdTMoEwkz1MGQ4TY9hs9gAoqyEgQWWyJvlcuRckA)

Comment: See also [TypeScript issue #16069](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069)

Answer (score 2):

This makes ts not angry.

```
const rawResponse = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
const response = rawResponse.filter((res) => res.status === 'fulfilled') as PromiseFulfilledResult<any>[];

const result = response[0].value
```

Comment: this is not ts. this is just js with extra work without the benefits of ts.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more context for handling arrays:

```
const fulfilled = (res.filter((r) => r.status === 'fulfilled') as PromiseFulfilledResult<any>[]).map(
  (r) => r.value
);
(res.filter((r) => r.status === 'rejected') as PromiseRejectedResult[]).forEach((r) =>
  console.warn(r.status, r.reason)
);
```